# PHP Security - Database Credentials in Docroot

Tags: php, security, mysqli

Is it considered secure to have your security credentials for a MySQL connection in the PHP file that is being requested from the server? For example, does `localhost/query.php?param=1&param=2` pose a threat if the first lines of `query.php` are credentials to connect to the databse?

Edit: Judging by the immediate comments and downvote, I want to clarify the params are not the credentials themselves, but they exist at the beginning of the `query.php` file. Is the only downside (a big one) that if your server has a problem processing your PHP that it will send the credentials in plaintext?

Comment: Why in God's name would you need such a thing? P.S: I was not the one who downgraded you, although I should... Give more explanation or delete the question... please!

Comment: Nor was I :) comment removed

Comment: I have no intention of passing the credentials over HTTP, the question is having the credentials in the script. Is it considered poor practice to access the `query.php` file that has direct access to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `query.php` is a real file it could potentionally become a security issue, because it means the file with the credentials is in the doc root (i.e. accessible by the public).

If you server is incorrectly configured / broken for whatever reason the PHP file would not be interpreted but rendered as plain text. Making your credentials public.

Always put sensitive stuff outside thew document root and include it.

So normally you would have only [a single php file](https://github.com/PeeHaa/Requestable/blob/master/public/index.php) in your document root which includes [a file outside the document root](https://github.com/PeeHaa/Requestable/blob/master/bootstrap.php).

Comment: Yes. **Always** place all the php files outside of the docroot.